# help understanding calculus derivation of sum of squares

Tags: calculus

The photo is from Strang's Calculus.  He is trying to find the discrete function $f$ for the sum of $n$ squares.  He knows that the integral is $x^3/3$ and uses this as a starting point and then calculates correction factors to adjust the function $f$.

I don't understand how, when looking at the error terms, he calculates his correction terms.

His error terms seem to be $-n + 1/3$.  To correct for the $1/3$, he subtracts $1/3n$ from the sum (why?).  To put back $n$ in the difference he adds $1/2n(n+1)$ to the sum (why?). I don't understand how he arrives at equation $(7)$.  I'm probably missing a few intermediary steps.

Can someone spell these out for me?  Thank you very much.

[image: strang's calculus]

Comment: Alternately, use $(n+1)^3=n^3+3n^2+3n+1~$ to write $~\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^N(3n^2+3n+1)=(N+1)^3.~$ Now break the sum up into three sub-sums, and use $~\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^Nn=\dfrac{N(N+1)}2~$ to extract the value of $~\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^Nn^2$. The latter formula is a consequence of $(n+1)^2=n^2+2n+1,~$ which implies $~\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^N(2n+1)=(N+1)^2$.

Answer (score 0):

You want the difference of $f_n$ and $f_{n-1}$ to be $n^2$. Now $1/3$ is the extra term. So you want to find something in $f_n$ and $f_{n-1}$ such that their difference is $-1/3$.

Notice that the difference of $\frac{1}{3} n$ and $\frac{1}{3}(n-1)$ is $1/3$. So he subtract that term to cancel the $1/3$.

To add the term $n$, you will want a $f_n$ and $f_{n-1}$ such that their difference is $n$, which are $1+...+n$ and $1+...+(n-1)$.

I hope this made some difference.